# Merge pyspark dataframe rows based on the same ID

Tags: apache-spark, group-by, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to flatten hbase dataset. Individual has 2 types of data in other table, mail and phone. After joining them on rel_id=data_id i'm getting 2 separate records for one individual.

```
    |individual_id|rel_id|data_id|       mail|phone|role
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    |            1|   100|    100|a@gmail.com| null|secondary
    |            1|   200|    200|       null|  123|primary
    |            2|   300|    300|       null|  345|secondary
    |            2|   400|    400|b@gmail.com| null|primary
    ------------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible somehow to merge mail and phone columns for the same individual_id and create new columns for each data type role so i would have data like this:

```
    |individual_id|       mail|phone|mail_role |phone_role
    ------------------------------------------------------
    |            1|a@gmail.com|  123| secondary|primary
    |            2|b@gmail.com|  345|   primary|secondary
    -----------------------------------------------------
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by the `individual_id` and use [`pyspark.sql.functions.first`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.first) as the aggregation function. You will have to set the `ignorenulls` parameter of `first` to `True`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import first

df.groupBy("individual_id").agg(
    first("mail", ignorenulls=True).alias("mail"), 
    first("phone", ignorenulls=True).alias("phone")
).show()
#+-------------+-----------+-----+
#|individual_id|       mail|phone|
#+-------------+-----------+-----+
#|            1|a@gmail.com|  123|
#|            2|b@gmail.com|  345|
#+-------------+-----------+-----+
```

---

For the updated question, you could use [`pyspark.sql.functions.when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.when):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

df.groupBy("individual_id").agg(
    first("mail", ignorenulls=True).alias("mail"), 
    first("phone", ignorenulls=True).alias("phone"),
    first(when(col("mail").isNotNull(), col("role")), ignorenulls=True).alias("mail_role"),
    first(when(col("phone").isNotNull(), col("role")), ignorenulls=True).alias("phone_role"),
).show()
#+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+----------+
#|individual_id|       mail|phone|mail_role|phone_role|
#+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+----------+
#|            1|a@gmail.com|  123| seconary|   primary|
#|            2|b@gmail.com|  345|  primary| secondary|
#+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+----------+
```